# sbteclipse main and test resources overlapping

Tags: sbt, sbteclipse

Sbt-eclipse declares main/resources and test/resources as a eclipse src folder. If there are files with the same name in both folders the file from the test/resources overrides the one from main/resources.

Example:
I have two configuration files for log4j. One resides in test/resources and the other in main/resources. I have different log configs to silence the log during test execution. When executing a class out of eclipse the log4j configuration for my test environment is wrongly taken.

Is this the desired behavior? I think mixing main/resources and test/resources isn't a good idea because they may overlap.

My workaround is to exclude the test/resources from the eclipse source path after the sbt eclipse run. I think that would be a better default configuration.